# How to use in built Keras ADDITIVE ATTENTION Layer for image captioning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, attention-mechanism

I have Designed an ***Encoder-Decoder*** Model for ***Image Captioning***. Now, I want to improve my Model. So, I thought of putting an ***Attention Layer*** in my Encoder-Decoder model. But, I am struggling with how to use ***Keras Attention layer API*** in my model. What are the input and output of the Attention layer(i.e what is query, key ,value provided in documentation) and how to get them? 
Here we are using a feature vector of the image from a pre-trained Xception Model.
How to manipulate or change this code to add the Attention Layer of Keras Library (https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/additive_attention/) to built an image captioning Model to this Encoder-Decoder Model?  

Here is my Previous Encoder-Decoder Model..

````
def caption_model(vocab_size,max_len):
    
    
    # features from the CNN model squeezed from 2048 to 256 nodes
    inputs1 = Input(shape=(2048,))
    fe1 = Dropout(0.5)(inputs1)
    fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
    
    # LSTM sequence model
    inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
    se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
    se2 = Dropout(0.5)(se1)
    se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)
    
    # Merging both models
    decoder1 = add([fe2, se3])
    decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
    outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
    
    # tie it together [image, seq] [word]
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    # summarize model
    print(model.summary())
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
    
    return model
```
````